# Arraylist with two posting entries

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, treemap

I am new to collections. I need to know how I can use an ArrayList with two entries.
I am writing a program that reads a file and stores a string into a treemap and associating the string to an ArrayList with two columns(document id, count). I am wondering how I can do this. Can someone help me with some guidance on how I can do this? Here is how the system should be working:

[image]

For Eg:
If the program reads the word "Hello", the words need to be added to the treemap as Treemap("Hello", Arraylist).

The word Hello is associated with (DocumentID, Count) in an ArrayList.

Comment: Perhaps you could just try something, and ask us if you encounter some problems? Note that there are pretty good tutorials about these topics, and the JavaDocs are also quite helpful.

Comment: To put values into a `TreeMap`, you just use [`map.put(key, value) `](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#put(K,V)), where in your case the value ist the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Also see [the official Oracle tutorials on Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In arraylist , we can't store in key value pair so instead of arrayList you can use pair.
Pair <String, Integer> pair = new Pair <String, Integer> ("DocumentId", count);
TreeMap("Hello", pair);

Answer (score 0):

You can't put two values into an ArrayList. You could create a new class to store documentId and count. And then store this new Class in the List in the TreeMap:

```
public class CountPerDocument {
    private final String documentId;
    private final int count;
    
    CountPerDocument(String documentId, int count){

        this.documentId = documentId;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

And fill your Map like this

```
Map<String, List<CountPerDocument>> map = new TreeMap<>();
List<CountPerDocument> list = new ArrayList<>();
//add code to fill your list here
list.add(new CountPerDocument("yourId", 23));
map.put("term", list);
```

Comment: I am wondering how the retrieving works for this method? Say for Eg: 
Court, (S1,1) 
Court,(S2,5)
Does the map print all the values as needed?

Comment: Well map.get("term") returns List with all CountPerDocument, which include all Documents and how many times the term appears in per Document.

Comment: Hi, How do i print all the elements in the TreeMap as follows:
<String> <DocID - Count>